# Hibernate Criteria with scrollableResults.next() Returning one null object in list

Tags: hibernate

I am using scrollableResults to fetch data from view. I have created hbm mapping for view.
The result is consisting of the List, but this list is returning List of size 500 but containing null object at the position 198 in the List.

Thanks,
Sudhir

Comment: Resolved the issue the issue is due to one of the primary key field is null hence hibernate is not populating that object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue the issue is due to one of the primary key field is null hence hibernate is not populating that object